# Multipage Node.js Server Without Routing Bloat?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

Can I set up a multipage Node.js web server that does not require a unique route for *every* page?

I have a simple HTTP server set up using Node and Express, using EJS for view engine. My routing currently looks like this:

```
// routing
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/hig', routes.hig);
app.get('/proto', routes.proto);
app.get('/design', routes.design);
app.get('/process', routes.process);

app.get('/demo', routes.demo);

app.get('/api', api.index);
app.get('/api/rules', api.list);
app.get('/api/rules/:id', api.ruleid);
```

I'd like to be able to easily update my site to have pages such as `/hig/section1` and `/hig/section2` (and so on) without having to update the route table each time and restart the server. More importantly, I'd like to be able to quickly and easily make multiple versions of a `demo` and be able to link to them.

For example, create a new demo and link a user to `/demo/version23` while linking someone else to `/demo/version 35`, allowing me to illustrate different functionality without breaking previous demo sites. It would not be long until `/demo/version108` and beyond exist, so having a sane way to create these without having 108+ routes is preferable.

The only method I've been successful at so far is updating route tables. Is there another way I can point to different pages in the route table that will allow me to more easily add new pages?

Answer (score 1):

You should consider making part of url variable for ex as /hig/:section.

You should then get section as a parameter which you can use to map to different content, page or do any other logic that you want with that.

Comment: But to map a new url variable I would still need to update the routing callback function, and restart the server - correct? Is there a way I can just create a new page (`/hig/brandnewpage`) and it will work without having to restart the server?

Answer (score 0):

In my express api, I have a wildcard get. The endpoint var parses the keyword and then whatever you decided to do with that is up to you. In mine I have some if statements to change the database model etc but you don't need that... I would suggest keeping the 404 send, so if somebody hits an undesired url you can just give them whatever status code.

```
app.get('/:endpoint', function (req, res) {
    var endpoint = req.params.endpoint;

    if( endpoint == 'something' ){


    } else if( endpoint == 'something' ){


    } else { return res.send(404, { erorr: "That resource doesn't exist" }); }


    // Display the results

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented simple demo project to achieve multi-app structure.

https://github.com/hitokun-s/node-express-multiapp-demo

With this structure, you can easily set up and maintain each app independently.
I hope this would be a help for you.